# regarding flex syntax error

Tags: apache-flex

I keep getting the error syntax error expecting right parren befor public. -ide

public class FlashlightWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

```
@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
int[] appWidgetIds) {

Intent receiver = new Intent(context, FlashlightWidgetReceiver.class);
receiver.setAction("COM_FLASHLIGHT");
receiver.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, appWidgetIds);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, receiver, 0);

RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
R.layout.widget_layout);
views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button, pendingIntent);

appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, views);

}
}
```

Comment: This is android code you are showing, so why tag it flex?

Comment: because flex is a corrasponding programing that you can program android in flex itself is a program ie now known as flash builder 4.6

Comment: I think you have missed the point then, @Max. Flash builder 4.6 will indeed allow you to create an android app. But by writing Actionscript code which is then compiled with AIR to a .apk. By no means will you be able to compile native Android code with the flex compiler bundled in Flash Builder 4.6

Comment: ahh ok makes alot of sence then eclips be a better program ?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html